# How to pass variables to a createjs Tween function

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I want to be able to pass variables to a createjs Tween function:

```
function openPanel(id, pos) {
    //alert("This panel is: "+id+" and is pos: "+pos);
    createjs.Tween.get(id, {
        loop: false
    }).to({
        pos: 50
    }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4));
}
```

The id and pos vars are both strings- the values appear in the alert but the Tween isn't firing. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'tweenjs_count' of blah` http://jsfiddle.net/kqaxyuyq/

Comment: ok- not possible then- thanks @isherwood

Comment: That's not exactly what that means. I don't know what that property is or does. There may well be a workaround.

Comment: The `Tween.get` method accepts a target. A string ID is not a target that will work, it has to be a reference to an object that has tweenable properties on it. What does the ID represent?

Comment: Ok- thanks @Lanny. The ID references the created Shape that I want to tween- topPanel, btmPanel, etc. I want to swap the x or y property of the tween depending on the ID being passed. `openPanel("btmPanel", "y");`

Comment: The id will have to be resolved to the object it represents to be passed into TweenJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. If I understand correctly, you want to be able to pass in the name of a property to tween, along with the id of the object to tween it on.

I'm not sure how you are looking up objects by string id (since that's not something EaselJS does internally), so I've edited your code to work on an object reference instead:

```
var myShape = new createjs.Shape();
// .... etc.
openPanel(myShape, "x");

function openPanel(target, prop) {
    var tweenProps = {};
    tweenProps[prop] = 50; // dynamic property access.

    createjs.Tween.get(target, {
        loop: false
    }).to(tweenProps, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4));
}
```

As you can see, I used dynamic property access (via square brackets) to set up my tween value object, which I then pass in to the `to()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [change](http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html#method_to) parameter and listen for changes while the Tween is running. But you will need to tween 'something' like alpha or x/y. I'm not sure 'pos' is a tween able property..

```
createjs.Tween.get(id, {override:true}).to({x:100}).addEventListener("change",handleChange);
     function handleChange(event) {
         // The id object with changed.
         // do something with 'pos'
     }
```

Comment: TweenJS will tween any value. Numeric values will tween as expected, and other values will "change" based on the tween time (including strings, booleans, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The id must be an object not string. U can give a name to each shape, pass the shape then get its name to decide x or y.